# 'Cursorline' in the setting of 'wordwrap' in VIM

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm writing some documents using VIM, and I don't like to create my own line breaks. Instead I just use ":set nowrap&" & "set lbr". I also have "set cursorline" activated.

The problem is that the cursorline will underline the entire block of text rather than the line I'm working on.

Is there a way to make cursorline pretend that my soft-wrapped lines are just regular lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:h cursorlinopt`:

> ```
> 'cursorlineopt' 'culopt' string (default: "number,line")
>           local to window
>           {not available when compiled without the +syntax
>           feature}
>   Comma separated list of settings for how 'cursorline' is displayed.
>   Valid values:
>   "line"      Highlight the text line of the cursor with
>           CursorLine hl-CursorLine.
>   "screenline"    Highlight only the screen line of the cursor with
>           CursorLine hl-CursorLine.
>   "number"    Highlight the line number of the cursor with
>           CursorLineNr hl-CursorLineNr.
> ```

You can use `set cursorlineopt=number,screenline` to accomplish what you want.